# MondoDB: Finding documents match all fields of a list objects

Tags: c#, mongodb

For example I have a collection with the following structure

```
{
   a: int,
   b: int,
   c: int
}
```

and I have an array of objects:

```
[
   { a = 1; b = 2},
   { a = 2; b = 3}
]
```

and I want to find all the documents in the collection, which match to item in the array of objects, like

```
a = 1 & b = 2 || a = 2 & b = 3
```

does anyone know how can I achieve this with mongoDB query ?
thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 2, b: 3 }]
})
```

You can see the result at here:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/1elUwbpwa8m